# How to display and use operator properties in a custom UI panel?

Tags: python, properties, operator, panel

For example, as you can see in the keymap preferences, there are operators that have properties, like this Smooth Vertices:

[image]

With this little code `row.operator("mesh.vertices_smooth")` I can make a button to execute this operator in my UI panel

[image]

So how can I do the same with those properties and checkboxes, for them to show up in my custom panel, so then I can set some settings before clicking the button?

This is in blender 2.8 by the way..

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set new property like this:

```
bpy.types.Scene.my_use_x=bpy.props.BoolProperty()
row.prop(context.scene, 'my_use_x')
```

And set property of operator like this:

```
operator = row.operator("mesh.vertices_smooth")
operator.use_x = context.scene.my_use_x
operator.use_y = False
operator.factor = 2
```

I do not use blender 2.8 and I did not test this. But it should work.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Also I should probably say that I'm a python newbie, so I almost have no clue how to deal with your code haha. But I'll see what I can do with it. Thanks again.

Comment: If this answer solved Your problem, please accept it. If not, I can still help You.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, it's my first time asking a question here on this site, so I don't know how things work here, no idea how to accept something. I upvoted your answer but somehow it doesn't show up either. And no, unfortunately I wasn't able to achieve what I want yet, as I have no idea how to deal with your code. All I want is to display those number fields in my custom panel, so I can use them there instead of going to the keymap settings.